# How to handle extra rows generated while Splitting comma separated values of a column into rows in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am facing an issue while splitting the value of an OTA Field into rows, here I want two rows with value ANR in the OTA field while I am getting 3 rows.
Output is giving 4 rows although I should get only 3 rows, 2 for Diesel traction where OTA is ANR, ANR and 1 row for Electric traction where OTA is LL, I am not getting why it is giving one extra row for ANR, please guide.

Query used is :

```
SELECT TRAIN_ID,TRAIN_NUMBER,TRAIN_START_DATE,TRAIN_TYPE,TRACTION,TRAIN_SRC,TRAIN_DSTN,
     REGEXP_SUBSTR(OTA,'[^,]+', 1, level)AS OTA 
     FROM 
    (
    SELECT TRAIN_ID,TRAIN_NUMBER,TRAIN_START_DATE,TRAIN_TYPE,TRACTION,TRAIN_SRC,TRAIN_DSTN,
       (CASE WHEN (MULTIPLE_UNIT='1' AND OTA='ANR') THEN 'ANR,ANR'
         WHEN (MULTIPLE_UNIT='1' AND (IS_BANKING=1 OR IS_AEB=1) AND OTA='LL') THEN 'LL,AR,AR'
         WHEN (MULTIPLE_UNIT='1' AND OTA='LL') THEN 'LL,AR'
         WHEN (MULTIPLE_UNIT='0' AND OTA='ANR')THEN 'ANR'
         WHEN (MULTIPLE_UNIT='0' AND (IS_BANKING=1 OR IS_AEB=1) AND OTA='LL') THEN 'LL,AR'
         WHEN (MULTIPLE_UNIT='0' AND OTA='LL') THEN 'LL'         
         END)AS OTA
          FROM SCHEDULED_RUN 
          WHERE TRAIN_NUMBER='12543' AND TRAIN_START_DATE='06-May-2021'
          AND SRC_SERIAL_NUMBER=1
        )CONNECT BY LEVEL<= regexp_count(OTA, ',')+1 and prior TRAIN_ID=TRAIN_ID and prior sys_guid() IS NOT NULL
```

The Output of the Inner query is :

[image]

The output of the Outer query is :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting too many rows because you have the same train ID twice in the inner query, and your `connect-by` doesn't allow for that. As the distinguishing feature appears to be the traction flag, you can add that to the conditions:

```
CONNECT BY LEVEL<= regexp_count(OTA, ',')+1
and prior TRAIN_ID=TRAIN_ID
and prior TRACTION=TRACTION
and prior sys_guid() IS NOT NULL
```

@Littlefoot's approach also works, of course.

But creating a delimited string just to immediately split it again seems a bit painful. You might want to consider just creating the right number of rows in the first place via `UNION` and logic in each branch; something like (if I've followed the existing case expression properly):

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM SCHEDULED_RUN 
  WHERE TRAIN_NUMBER = 12543 AND TRAIN_START_DATE = DATE '2021-05-06'
  AND SRC_SERIAL_NUMBER = 1
)
-- always at least one row
SELECT TRAIN_ID, TRAIN_NUMBER, TRAIN_START_DATE, TRAIN_TYPE, TRACTION, TRAIN_SRC, TRAIN_DSTN, OTA
FROM CTE
UNION ALL
-- if multiple unit = 1 and OTA = ANR then repeat same row
SELECT TRAIN_ID, TRAIN_NUMBER, TRAIN_START_DATE, TRAIN_TYPE, TRACTION, TRAIN_SRC, TRAIN_DSTN, OTA
FROM CTE
WHERE OTA ='ANR' AND MULTIPLE_UNIT = 1
UNION ALL
-- LL with banking/AEB gets an AR row...
SELECT TRAIN_ID, TRAIN_NUMBER, TRAIN_START_DATE, TRAIN_TYPE, TRACTION, TRAIN_SRC, TRAIN_DSTN, 'AR' AS OTA
FROM CTE
WHERE OTA = 'LL' AND (IS_BANKING = 1 OR IS_AEB = 1)
UNION ALL
-- ... and a second AR row if multiple unit = 1
SELECT TRAIN_ID, TRAIN_NUMBER, TRAIN_START_DATE, TRAIN_TYPE, TRACTION, TRAIN_SRC, TRAIN_DSTN, 'AR' AS OTA
FROM CTE
WHERE OTA = 'LL' AND (IS_BANKING = 1 OR IS_AEB = 1) AND MULTIPLE_UNIT = 1
```

I've also changed the date comparison to use a real date rather than a string (which relies on implicit conversion), and also some other comparisons to use numbers instead of strings.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f482ed47f23b8ce3d3d50f8566bf1a68)

Answer (score 2):

Duplicates, yes. Because you did it partially wrong. Should have been

```
SQL> with tin (train_id, train_number, train_start_date,
  2    train_type, traction, train_src, train_dstn, ota) as
  3    (select '1111X', 12543, date '2021-05-06', 'RAJ', 'D', 'JHS', 'PRYJ', 'ANR,ANR' from dual union all
  4     select '1111X', 12543, date '2021-05-06', 'RAJ', 'E', 'JHS', 'PRYJ', 'LL'      from dual
  5    )
  6  select train_id, train_number, train_start_date,
  7    train_type, traction, train_src, train_dstn,
  8    --
  9    regexp_substr(ota, '[^,]+', 1, column_value) ota
 10  from tin
 11    cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 12                                   connect by level <= regexp_count(ota, ',') + 1
 13                                  ) as sys.odcinumberlist));

TRAIN TRAIN_NUMBER TRAIN_ST TRA T TRA TRAI OTA
----- ------------ -------- --- - --- ---- ----------------------------
1111X        12543 06.05.21 RAJ D JHS PRYJ ANR
1111X        12543 06.05.21 RAJ D JHS PRYJ ANR
1111X        12543 06.05.21 RAJ E JHS PRYJ LL

SQL>
```

where

- `tin` CTE is result of your "inner query"
- note cross join I used ...
- ... as well as `column_value` in `regexp_substr` instead of `level`

Answer (score 1):

This is can be solved by not using delimited strings (therefore, you do not need to split the strings) and, instead, using a collection (or `VARRAY` such as `SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST`) data type:

```sql
SELECT t.TRAIN_ID,
       t.TRAIN_NUMBER,
       t.TRAIN_START_DATE,
       t.TRAIN_TYPE,
       t.TRACTION,
       t.TRAIN_SRC,
       t.TRAIN_DSTN,
       o.COLUMN_VALUE AS OTA 
FROM   (
  SELECT TRAIN_ID,
         TRAIN_NUMBER,
         TRAIN_START_DATE,
         TRAIN_TYPE,
         TRACTION,
         TRAIN_SRC,
         TRAIN_DSTN,
         ( CASE
           WHEN (MULTIPLE_UNIT='1' AND OTA='ANR')
           THEN SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('ANR','ANR')
           WHEN (MULTIPLE_UNIT='1' AND (IS_BANKING=1 OR IS_AEB=1) AND OTA='LL')
           THEN SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('LL','AR','AR')
           WHEN (MULTIPLE_UNIT='1' AND OTA='LL')
           THEN SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('LL','AR')
           WHEN (MULTIPLE_UNIT='0' AND OTA='ANR')
           THEN SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('ANR')
           WHEN (MULTIPLE_UNIT='0' AND (IS_BANKING=1 OR IS_AEB=1) AND OTA='LL')
           THEN SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('LL','AR')
           WHEN (MULTIPLE_UNIT='0' AND OTA='LL')
           THEN SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('LL')
           END
         ) AS OTAs
  FROM   SCHEDULED_RUN
  WHERE  TRAIN_NUMBER='12543'
  AND    TRAIN_START_DATE=DATE '2021-05-06'
  AND    SRC_SERIAL_NUMBER=1
) t
CROSS JOIN TABLE(t.OTAs) o
```

*(From Oracle 12, you can change `CROSS JOIN` to `CROSS APPLY` or, if appropriate, `OUTER APPLY`.)*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE SCHEDULED_RUN (
  src_serial_number, train_id, train_number, train_start_date, train_type, traction, train_src, train_dstn, ota, multiple_unit, is_banking, is_aeb
) as
  select 1, '1111X', 12543, date '2021-05-06', 'RAJ', 'A', 'JHS', 'PRYJ', 'ANR', 1, 0, 0 from dual union all
  select 1, '1111X', 12543, date '2021-05-06', 'RAJ', 'B', 'JHS', 'PRYJ', 'LL',  1, 1, 0 from dual union all
  select 1, '1111X', 12543, date '2021-05-06', 'RAJ', 'C', 'JHS', 'PRYJ', 'LL',  1, 0, 0 from dual union all
  select 1, '1111X', 12543, date '2021-05-06', 'RAJ', 'D', 'JHS', 'PRYJ', 'ANR', 0, 0, 0 from dual union all
  select 1, '1111X', 12543, date '2021-05-06', 'RAJ', 'E', 'JHS', 'PRYJ', 'LL',  0, 0, 1 from dual union all
  select 1, '1111X', 12543, date '2021-05-06', 'RAJ', 'F', 'JHS', 'PRYJ', 'LL',  0, 0, 0 from dual;
```

Outputs:

> | TRAIN_ID | TRAIN_NUMBER | TRAIN_START_DATE | TRAIN_TYPE | TRACTION | TRAIN_SRC | TRAIN_DSTN | OTA |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1111X | 12543 | 06-MAY-21 | RAJ | A | JHS | PRYJ | ANR |
> | 1111X | 12543 | 06-MAY-21 | RAJ | A | JHS | PRYJ | ANR |
> | 1111X | 12543 | 06-MAY-21 | RAJ | B | JHS | PRYJ | LL |
> | 1111X | 12543 | 06-MAY-21 | RAJ | B | JHS | PRYJ | AR |
> | 1111X | 12543 | 06-MAY-21 | RAJ | B | JHS | PRYJ | AR |
> | 1111X | 12543 | 06-MAY-21 | RAJ | C | JHS | PRYJ | LL |
> | 1111X | 12543 | 06-MAY-21 | RAJ | C | JHS | PRYJ | AR |
> | 1111X | 12543 | 06-MAY-21 | RAJ | D | JHS | PRYJ | ANR |
> | 1111X | 12543 | 06-MAY-21 | RAJ | E | JHS | PRYJ | LL |
> | 1111X | 12543 | 06-MAY-21 | RAJ | E | JHS | PRYJ | AR |
> | 1111X | 12543 | 06-MAY-21 | RAJ | F | JHS | PRYJ | LL |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a3b99264157071680d691ef30a499b54)*